# Bootstrap carousel breaks my bootstrap-based library

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm developing a [bootstrap-based webchat client](https://github.com/throoze/chattigo-webchat). I packaged my client as a library, using webpack, but the problem is that, when included in a page where a bootstrapjs carousel is active, the widget generated by my library becomes invisible during the transition between every slide. Maybe it's a thing of name clashes, but I seriously don't know how to approach this problem. Where should I look? the simplest code that is being affected by this problem is:

```
<div id="chattigo-webchat-container">
    <button data-reactroot=""
            class="collapsed btn btn-sm btn-default"
            id="chattigo-widget"
            type="button"
            style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(8, 83, 203);">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Any Ideas? how is this clashing with [bootstrap js's carousel](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp)?

[Here](http://ucinf2015.upmedia.cl/) is a sample page where you can see the undesired behavior.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: What is undesired?

Comment: I honestly would be more worried about the 35s load time

Comment: @Adam Buchanan Smith.  Te undesired behavior is that, in Chrome, the chat widget I'm developing (the little circle with the user icon in the bottom left corner)  blinks every time the slider transitions.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I just checked your code. You should try changing the overflow value from **hidden** to **visible**, and it will work fine.

```
#chattigo-webchat-container {
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I hope this fix works fine for you too. Just let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot Santi! :)